# How to make a foreach of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, qliksense, mashup

I am currently building a mashup in Qlik Sense in JavaScript and jQuery. I have made some data selection and I have put them in a variable object :

```
var CurrentSelec = app1.selectionState().selections;
console.log(CurrentSelec);`
console.log(typeof CurrentSelec);
```

This is what I get on my browser console :

[image: CurrentSelec Object]

I'm trying to show the qSelected value in a Foreach :

I have tried with Javascript :

```
for(var index in CurrentSelec) { 
    console.log(index.qSelected);
}
```

I have tried with jQuery:

```
$.each(CurrentSelec, function(i, index) {
  console.log(index.qSelected)
});
```

But my browser console do not show the log of my **foreach**.

Do you know how to properly make a **foreach** of an object and show its content on a browser console, please ?

Regards.

Comment: `CurrentSelec` is *not* an object, it is an **array**. If it were an object, the first line of your image would say `Object` instead of `Array(1)`, and the `typeof CurrentSelect` would output *`Object {}`* instead of `object`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Object.keys() method, which returns an array of the keys in an object. Then we run that through an Array.forEach() method. for example

```
Object.keys(lunch).forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item); // key
    console.log(lunch[item]); // value
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your CurrentSelec variable is an array, not an ordinary object, so just use its `forEach` method:

```
CurrentSelec.forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el.qSelected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate object using javascript `for in` loop.

For e.g. `CurrentSelec` is your object.

```
for(key in CurrentSelec){
    //key is your object's main query.
    //CurrentSelec is your object's nested array if has.
    console.log(key);
    console.log(CurrentSelec[key]);
}
```

Comment: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

With your JavaScript example, you are incorrectly navigating through the Object. In order to move through it, use `[]` and the variable you set. For example,

```
for (var index in CurrentSelec) {
  console.log(CurrentSelec[index].qSelected);
}
```

This chooses each child inside of `CurrentSelec` and prints out its corresponding `qSelected` value.

In your example, when you say `for (var index in CurrentSelec) {...};`, you are saying **for each child inside of `CurrentSelec`**, set `index = child` (where child is only a key to your `CurrentSelec` Object), and then proceed with the `for` loop.

Therefore, when you say `console.log(index.qSelected)`, you are trying to navigate to the `qSelected` value under `index`, which will never exist. Instead you should navigate through the **parent** Object using each `index` you receive in your `for` loop.

Comment: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @Santi Ah, I neglected the fact that it is an array. However, it is still valid (as long as you iterate correctly).

Comment: Sure. Just figured I'd provide some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code and see if it works, instead of **CurrentSelec** use **CurrentSelec[0]**

```
$.each(CurrentSelec[0], function(i, index) {
  console.log(index.qSelected)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var index in CurrentSelec[0]) {
 console.log(index.qSelected);
}
```

try this

Comment: Consider adding some more substance to your answer. Just giving OP a code to substitute doesn't really explain much.

Answer (score 0):

Some info is missing here (and please rename to 'currentSelec) , but do:

```
CurrentSelec.forEach(function(item){
         console.log(item.qSelected)
    })
```

What you did is iteration on the keys of the Array, and not the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery as like this,

```
$.each(CurrentSelec, function( key, value ) {
   alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

I am sure it helps,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you mixed up Arrays and Objects. 
Looking at the picture you provided I think you have an Array which contains Objects.

```
//Naming indicates mutliple selections
app1.selectionState().selections;
```

Looping over an array is easy, accessing a object value too:

```
// CurrentSelec = [{qSelected : '1'},{qSelected : '2'}];
CurrentSelec.forEach ( selection => console.log(selection.qSelected) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var displayArray = [{id:1,dispName:"abc"},{id:2,dispName:"aaaa"},{id:3,dispName:"bbbb"},{id:4,dispName:"xxxxx"},{id:5,dispName:"www"}]
      displayArray.forEach(obj => {
      console.log(obj)
      });
```